# Division of Rome and Its Eventual Decline

Tags: ancient-rome, roman-empire

What was the effect of dividing Rome into three separate administrative states around 44BC?  How did this contribute to the fall of the empire?

Comment: Which division, specifically, are you referring to?

Answer (score 4):

The division of Rome by the second triumvirate was into more than the three parts assigned to Octavian, Antony and Lepidus. For example, all of Italy was assigned to the Senate as you can see in the following map:

[image: Division of territory by the second triumvirate]

There was no specific results of this tending towards the "fall" of the empire. In fact, the empire grew for another 200 years after this. The main change it presaged was turning the empire into the personal fiefdom of dictators, as opposed to being composed of praefectures controlled by governors appointed by the senate, which it had been under the republic.

The division of the triumvirs also set the pattern for the division of the empire under the emperors starting with Octavian, which was to divide it into four parts: Gaul, Italy, Illyricum (Dacia, Macedonia and Greece), and the East.

Comment: It is a stretch for the OP call the second triumvirate division as a 'separate administrative state' as it was very ad-hoc affair. Slices were at times given to Sextus Pompey and Lepidus was stripped of his share without any major reorganization needed.  It was more in the line of a super Proconsul over the region than any kind of national split.  Even right before the final war between Antony and Octavian there was a pretense of cooperation between the parts of the Empire.

Comment: @Oldcat The establishment of the Second Triumvirate was done by a plebiscite of Publius Titius and codified into law as the Triumviri Rei Publicae Constituendae Consulari Potestate. It had the most official legal establishment possible at the time. Cf. Res Gestae Divi Augusti, Monumentum Ancyranum, i. 8.

Comment: Sure, but after that none of them bothered to go back and ask for votes for any adjustments they needed to make.